# Check if image URL exists

Tags: java

I'm using this function to check wheather an url image exists or not :

```
public Boolean testImage(String url) {  
    try {  
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));  
        //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://someimage.jpg"));  
        if (image != null) {  
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        System.err.println("URL error with image");  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        System.err.println("IO error with image");  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    return null;  
}
```

And then i call this method :

```
if (testImage("URLHERE")) {
    System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

The problem is when i execute this code, i got this result :

```
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
Yes
IO error with image
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1369)
```

I just want get Yes or No, not an error, i know that in some cases the url isn't valid and that's what i what to determin. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Return `false` from both of the exception blocks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are not returning a boolean when you catch any of your exceptions.

Try this:

```
public Boolean testImage(String url){  
        try {  
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));  
            //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://someimage.jpg"));  
            if(image != null){  
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            System.err.println("URL error with image");  
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            System.err.println("IO error with image");  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;  
        }
        return false;  
    }
```